# How to tokenize indents in Coco/R (Python, Boo like indentation)

Tags: c#, cocor

It there a well known way, how to implement in Coco/R tokenizing indents like in Python/Boo?

Coco/R ignores whitespaces, but I need somehow to generate beginBlock/endBlock tokens, based on next line indent.

Right now, I use preprocessor, which inserts '{', '}', and ';' in input stream, by comparing indents between lines. In Coco/R grammar I use curved braces as beginBlock/endBlock tokens. It works well if input stream has no commens (which could be also nested). As soon as unordered comments coming, intentation comparison logic fails.

Implementing a preprocessor, which traces a comments looks like overenginering to me.

So the question is, is it generally possible to parse indent based grammar with Coco/R? 
Or should I try something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a ideal way to do this.

- wrap GetNextToken with method that
  compares stream positions of the next
  token with the last one.
- if position.Y is changed, but
  position.X increased N tabs, inject N
  virtual INDENT tokens.
- if position.Y is changed, but
  position.X decreased N tabs, inject N
  virtual DENDENT tokens.
- if position.Y is changed, but
  position.X is not, inject virtual
  SEPARATOR token.
- if position.Y is not changed, return
  original next token.
- if previous token was a soft break (in python \),
  ignore logic above.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Coco/R only ignores blanks (spaces) by default. Tabs are not ignored:

> 2.3.5 White space
>   Characters such as blanks, tabulators or end-of-line
>   symbols are usually considered as 
>   white space that should be  ignored by
>   the scanner. Blanks are ignored by
>   default. If  other characters should
>   be ignored as well the user has to
>   specify them in the  following way:
>
> WhiteSpaceDecl = "IGNORE" Set.
>
> Example  IGNORE '\t' + '\r' + '\n'

I haven't tested this, but my guess is that you should overwrite the default behavior of the Scanner:

```
Token NextToken() {
    while (ch == ' ' ||
        false
    ) NextCh();
```

The easiest way to do this is by first modifying the generated code until it works OK and then making the same changes in the frame files (`Scanner.frame` and `Parser.frame`) so you won't loose the changes after you regenerate the code.